# Terminology for half the difference

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for half of the difference between two numbers
$$x=\dfrac{a-b}{2}$$

Analogous to say the mean?

Comment: I sincerely doubt it

Comment: I do not think that there is a terminlog better than "distance from the mid-point"

Comment: In Italian, this is called _semidifferenza_, analogous to _semisomma_ (which is a translation of semi-sum, a term that exists also in English). You could use it as an extension - semidifference (maybe)?

Comment: Or simply "the mean of $\;a\,,\,-b\;$ ...

Comment: MAD ([mean absolute derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation#Mean_absolute_deviation_around_the_mean))?

Comment: @Easymode44 Now you say it, in Spanish we also have "semidiferencia". It's more likely that semi-sum is the English translation of some Latin term, but they forgot to translate the parallel term semi-difference; that's maybe why in both Romance languages the term exists while in English doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can interpret it as **$1\over \sqrt 2$ times as much as the [Standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of $a$ and $b$**. According to definition $$\sigma=\sqrt{(a-m)^2+(a-m)^2}$$where $m={a+b\over 2}$ therefore $$\sigma=\sqrt{{(a-b)^2}\over 2}=\sqrt 2{\left|{a-b\over 2}\right|}$$and we obtain$$\left|{a-b\over 2}\right|={\sigma(a,b)\over \sqrt 2}$$but I don't know whether any other interpretation exists.